# ` ember server` throws error, not able to run the app

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am a absolute new with `emberjs`. I am just following this tutorial to create my first app : `http://yoember.com/` but as like tutorials instruction I am running `ember server` but I thrown with error like :

```
The Broccoli Plugin: [ConfigReplace] failed with:
Error: Build Canceled: Broccoli Builder ran into an error with Funnel plugin. �
    at new BroccoliBuildError (F:\EmberJS\libraray-app\node_modules\broccoli-builder\lib\broccoli-build-error.js:40:9)
    at F:\EmberJS\libraray-app\node_modules\broccoli-builder\lib\builder.js:168:19
    at tryCatch (F:\EmberJS\libraray-app\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:539:12)
    at invokeCallback (F:\EmberJS\libraray-app\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:554:13)
    at publish (F:\EmberJS\libraray-app\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:522:7)
    at publishRejection (F:\EmberJS\libraray-app\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:457:3)
    at flush (F:\EmberJS\libraray-app\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:2414:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at:
    at ConfigReplace.Plugin (F:\EmberJS\libraray-app\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\index.js:7:31)
    at new ConfigReplace (F:\EmberJS\libraray-app\node_modules\broccoli-config-replace\index.js:13:10)
    at EmberApp.index (F:\EmberJS\libraray-app\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:686:12)
    at EmberApp.toArray (F:\EmberJS\libraray-app\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:1661:12)
    at EmberApp.toTree (F:\EmberJS\libraray-app\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:1684:38)
    at module.exports (F:\EmberJS\libraray-app\ember-cli-build.js:22:14)
    at Builder.setupBroccoliBuilder (F:\EmberJS\libraray-app\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:56:19)
    at new Builder (F:\EmberJS\libraray-app\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:30:10)
    at ServeTask.run (F:\EmberJS\libraray-app\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\tasks\serve.js:24:55)
    at Promise.resolve.then (F:\EmberJS\libraray-app\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:242:46)


Livereload server on http://localhost:49153
```

How to fix this?

Comment: What part of the tutorial did you reach? Was the error displayed in the browser or on the Command Line?

Comment: On the command line

Comment: Was this the very beginning of the tutorial, where you calling ember serve for the first time?

Comment: Yes it's in very beginning

Comment: I'm not able to recreate your error. I followed the instructions pretty exactly. Did you fiddle with any of the files?

Comment: I guess I don't have the necessary privilege with my current folder.( I am working with corporate company) do we have any special approach to handle this scenario?

Comment: Same here. I also don't have admin privileges. You shouldn't need admin to do an `ember serve` (unless theres maybe first-time configurations that I don't remember).